# Django how to joint a set of number into a comma separated string?

Tags: django

I am new to django, sorry if the question is too basic.

I passed a model collection into template:

```
{% for sub in subject.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

I hope to have a hidden field to save the list of subject ids so as to post it back.

```
<input id="id_subject_id_list" name="subject_id_list" type="hidden" value="{{ subject_id_list }}" />
```

Not sure how to obtain the variable 'subject_id_list'
I tried something like this in the for loop, but cannot get it work out.

```
{{ subject_id_list=subject_id_list|add:sub.id|slugify|add:"," }}
```

Comment: OK, I figured out I don't have to do this in template, I can build up the string in view at fist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the template builtin `join`:

```
{{ subject_id_list|join:"," }}
```

doc is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join.